# how to get webview content android after loadurl

Tags: webview, android-webview

Here is My Code.

I just want to get the page content from the Webview after load the URL .

On Android, I have a WebView that is displaying a page.

How do I get the page source without requesting the page again?

It seems WebView should have some kind of WebResourceResponse () method in Android 3.0 but don't know how to use it.

```
 public class WebActivity extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://xyz.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());



 }



       private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {

      public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)
      {
        return null;


      }

      @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
           /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
           mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");

        }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for future visitors, the following should work.

First, you need to define an interface such as:

```
final class LoadingInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void outputHTML(final String html){
        //do what ever you want with html
    }
}
```

Then on your WebView call
`webView.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadingInterface(), "INTERFACE");`

In `onPageFinished` put:

```
String js = "javascript:"
        +"var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;"
        +"window.INTERFACE.outputSchedule(html);";
        webView.loadUrl(js);
```

If you only need part of a page, you can replace `getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` with something like `getElementById('partOfPage')`